# Windows Iot Error : This Process exited with a native exception

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi, windowsiot

Im Working on an app thats build with visual studio 2017 and run on RaspberryPi 3
First, the program was run without problems
After that, I get the following error:

---

An Issue In The Jamsaz.InjectionWeights.exe process caused it fail to active . this process exited with a native exception 
to debug the issue , open project properties , and configure the project to run under a native debugger . more information can be found in the debug pane of the output window ( Debug --> Windows -> Output).

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo9IS.png)

After searching the internet
I tested the solutions that were said
But the problem was not resolved

### Solutions Made :

- build Release and then Build Debug
- Clean Solution and Rebuild
- Add Package with PowerShell

  ```
   add-appxpackage   C:\Program Files (x86)\MicrosofSDKs\Windows... 
   Microsoft.VCLibs.x86.Debug.14.00.appx   And X64
  ```
- Change Raspberry Pi OS

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [Getting Started with .NET Native](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/getting-started-with-net-native) for exhaustive information, and pay attention to that:

> Note that there are some known compatibility issues between compiling UWP app projects with the .NET Native tool chain and without it. Refer to the [migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/migrating-your-windows-store-app-to-net-native) for more information.

In addition,you can refer to [.NET Native General Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/net-native-general-troubleshooting) for troubleshooting potential issues with .NET Native.

Comment: Thank you for answering . I'm checking in . But   in output windows there is Error : The program '[1660] Jamsaz.InjectionWeights.exe' has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135) 'A dependent dll was not found'.
Activation of the Windows Store app '930e206e-dd28-4760-84b2-f3a1f74801fe_93bj70ht6wkzp!App' failed with error 'The app didn't start'.